# android wear and mobile data comunication

Tags: android, wear-os

I am trying to get my wearable app to communicate with my mobile app. what I want to have happen is my wearable app to update whenever it is started but the issue I'm having is that the mobile app has to be running as well. but that seems redundant to me. I'm trying to display information on the wearable from the mobile app but if I have to have the mobile app running as well then what's the point in the wearable app;

I have looked into MessageAPI and DataApi examples and I can get them working but require both devices to be running. so I thought about looking into services. I was thinking about having a background service to send updates to the wearable or the wearable be able to contact the service but I can't seem to get any results.

Admittedly I'm still bit new at android and I have been trying to find a solution to this problem for a week. I think I might be going about this wrong so I need some help to get pointed in the right direction and hopefully a good example.

Comment: I think this is one of the [limitations of wearables](http://www.computerworld.com/article/3080588/wearables/downsides-to-wearables-limited-functions-inaccurate-data-no-cellular-connection.html) in that they are dependent on handheld devices. If you want Standalone Apps, checkout Android Wear 2.0 which is said to work independently of a phone. [Standalone apps for wearables](https://developer.android.com/wear/preview/features/standalone-apps.html) can work without access to an Android or iOS phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pro tip, read the docs docs...https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/events.html

Wearablelistenerservice is what you want.